# Insert HTML code inside SVG Text element in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, svg

I Want to add HTML on My SVG.I Found a Solution with foreignObject.But this Does Not Work on Internet Explorer .Any one Please Help

Comment: Create the whole thing as a html page and then add SVG into it rather than the other way round.

Comment: I Just Using one textbox on a SVG..